# Use realloc or a temporary array

Tags: c, realloc, temporary

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

int main ( int argc, char * argv [] ) {
  int alloc = 10;
  int i = 0;
  int *array = (int *) malloc (alloc * sizeof(*array));

  printf("Enter some integers, stops with EOF:\n");

  while( 1 ) {
    if( i > alloc - 1 ) {
        alloc *= 2;
        array = (int *) realloc (array, alloc * sizeof(*array)); 
    }

    if( scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1 ) 
      break;

    i++;
  }

  if( ! feof(stdin) ) {
      printf("Wrong input.\n");
      return 1; 
  }

  free(array);

  return 0;
}
```

I'd like to ask about the right way of using `realloc`.

The above code works fine. The array is dynamically expanding
according to the input.

However, I heard that the right way to do this is by using a
temporary array and I'd like to know why and how to do it.

Comment: if realloc fails you can still have your array pointer so you can later free it.

Comment: valter is right.  You want to store the result in another pointer... (which isn't the same as saying you want a "temporary array")

Comment: Yes I apologize. I edited the question as it was before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int *temp;
temp = (int *) realloc (array, alloc * sizeof(*array)); }
if(temp == NULL){free(array);}
else{
    array = temp;
    //continue
}
```

In your original code:

```
array = (int *) realloc (array, alloc * sizeof(*array)); }
```

if realloc fails `array = NULL`. You lost your pointer. You cant do `free(array);` any more.

Comment: One more thing. I tried this code but the program crashed. But it works when the condition if(temp==NULL){free...} else array=temp; is inside the above condition.

Comment: Change `sizeof(*array)` to `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Dont know why should I change it. Its practically the same but sizeof(*array) seems cleaner to me. I edited the code and it works but still dont know if its correct.

Comment: @Daymare So it works with sizeof(int) and dont work with sizeof(*array)?

Comment: It does not matter if you have sizeof(int) or sizeof(*array). It does not affect the code. So it works both time.

Comment: Avoid the parenthesis eg `realloc(array, alloc * sizeof*array);`. The parenthesis is needed when you have data types like `sizeof(int)`. sizeof is **not a function**

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the original code is wrong because I would lose a pointer as Valter says.

```
array = (int *) realloc (array, alloc * sizeof(*array)); } //wrong
```

But if I try Valters code the program would crash. See comments below.

```
int *temp;
temp = (int *) realloc (array, alloc * sizeof(*array)); } //Here ends body of condition
if(temp == NULL){free(array);}                            //for expanding array

else{                //Lets say we are in firts iteration. temp is not equal NULL
     array = temp;   //so we ran in the "else" where we try to asign temp to
     //continue      //array. But theres nothing in temp yet => Program crashes.
}
```

So I made a little change of code above which works well.

```
if( i > alloc - 1 ) {
    alloc *= 2;
    temp = (int *) realloc (array, alloc * sizeof(*array));

    if( temp == NULL ) {
        free(array);
        printf("Error allocating memory.\n");
        return 1; }

    array = temp; //Now we have confidence that temp would not be empty or what so ever
 } //Here ends body of condition for expanding array
```